# What's the type of a class object in python?

Tags: python, types

For example, in the given code snippet:

```py
class Test:
    variable: string

value1 = Test() 
value2 = Test
```

the `value1` has the type `Test` but what is the type of `value2`?

I know in other languages there is a type to signify a class object, but given that python type hinting is recent I can't seem to find information on it online.

Comment: It's `type`, try `print(type(value2))`

Comment: ... did you try `type(Test)`? It's `type`. All class objects are instances of the class `type`, which is the default metaclass. You can create your own metaclass by inheriting from `type`. Or are you asking how to type-hint that (not the same question)? Because I don't understand your reference to type hinting, what does that have to do with it? Python is a *strongly typed* language, every object has a type, and knows its type. Class objects aren't special in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Try by checking by:

```
print(type(value1))
print(type(value2))
```